# How to wake up epoll_wait() before any event happened?

Tags: c++, multithreading, epoll

I have a `Connection` object that represents a connection managed by `epoll`. On events, the `Connection::eventWrite()` or `Connection::eventRead()` are invoked. Connection is persistent (exists always).

I need to send data via that `Connection` from another thread, but don't want to access the object `Connection` directly, because I dont want to solve multithreading issues inside the `Connection` object (`Connection` is accessed from `epoll`-thread and from "sending thread"). Instead, I want to tell `epoll`-thread: "wake up and do something with `Connection`" --`epoll_wait()` should return and my code will find out that a `CUSTOM EVENT` is occured (and, for example, some function should be called, where the desired access to `Connection` will be performed (assign sending data to object, calling `writeEvent()`), then `epoll_wait()`-loop will be continued.

What kind of solutions exists for waking up a `epoll_wait()` and which one is faster? For now, I came up with creating a `pipe` (handled by the same `epoll`) and writing a byte `1` to it. What else IPC exists which can be expressed via `int` "epollable" file descriptor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Epoll can wait on `eventfd`. In your case, I'd create an `eventfd` and than trigger this event. I think, this is the cleanest solution.